# PayPal Pro IPN Method missing

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, recurring-contributions, ipn

When making recurring contributions, everything works fine when entering credit card info directly, but if one uses a PayPal account, the method (m=contribute) is missing in the IPN generated

(i.e., i=0c1df32e5c4f32d4f8ef1c2fe8e&m=&c=11058&r=95&b=465&p=14)

It should read i=xxxx&m=contribute&c=... like it does for IPNs generated using credit cards directly.

The recurring profile shows the status as Pending and the contributions show as Pending (Incomplete Transaction) in Civi through they are completing properly in PayPal.

Is this a bug or something on my side!?!? 
Running Civi 4.7.15 in WP. 
Any help is appreciated - thanks!
Karen

Answer (score 1):

Is this paypal pro or standard? For paypal pro all IPNS except for recurring are actually ignored, the outcome is resolved in realtime (ideally the IP would be a backup but Civi code doesn't implement that)

Comment: This is PayPal Pro recurring.