# Paypal Pro IPN failures for non-recurring payments

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, ipn

We have a paypal pro setup for a contribution page and the ipn response for a normal contribution looks like -

> {"transaction_subject":"","payment_date":"16:37:45 Sep 02, 2018 PDT","txn_type":"web_accept","last_name":"xxxx","receipt_id":"2600-0803-0809-7320","residence_country":"US","item_name":"Online Contribution: Personal Membership","payment_gross":"35.00","mc_currency":"USD","business":"xxx@xxx.org","payment_type":"instant","protection_eligibility":"Ineligible","verify_sign":"xxxx","payer_status":"unverified","payer_email":"xxx@xxx.com","txn_id":"7F410221CJ172415V","quantity":"1","receiver_email":"xxx@xxxx.org","first_name":"xxxx","invoice":"89272b33abe6e127f59343e2a9b44a2c","payer_id":"9X46HRFGKLWH2","receiver_id":"R6MXHRC5VK3G8","item_number":"","payment_status":"Completed","payment_fee":"1.07","mc_fee":"1.07","mc_gross":"35.00","custom":"","charset":"windows-1252","notify_version":"3.9","ipn_track_id":"xxxxx"}

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/17991/245 mentions that paypal pro ipn is only handled for recurring payments and others are simply ignored.

What seems incorrect to me is when an `rp_invoice_id`(not set for non-recurring payment) is missing in the response parameters, the payment processor is assumed to be of [Paypal Express type](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php#L99) and further handling is done with `handlePaymentExpress` function.

This function [throws an exception](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php#L567) when a payment is not of recurring type and hence sends a `failed` delivery status to paypal.

On the other side, civi contribution is completed and all works fine in the backend. It is just that paypal isn't getting a positive response for the ipn URL and hence the Paypal system send us a warning email re failed IPN calls about 2x/day.

Is this something missing in the code which incorrectly sets `payment express` for not seeing `rp_invoice_id` in the response? Should it also check for another param before deciding it as a paypal express transaction?

Update: CiviCRM version - 5.5.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you on? We're on 5.5 and we are getting notices from Paypal about failures.

Comment: Updated the question with the civi version.

Comment: So there have been a number of tweaks/fixes to the paypal code in core over the last few versions, resolving various issues with recurring etc.  @jitendra-fuzion it sounds like that may have allowed another bug to surface - if you can create a PR I'll happily review